# Beaglebone Ubuntu upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 PWM issue

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, gpio, beagleboneblack, pwm

I've updated my Beaglebone Black based hardware from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. I can still connect through ethernet, but my PWM (driving LEDs) stopped working.

I did a `sudo do-release-upgrade` in Ubuntu 16.04 to upgrade to 18.04. The program running the PWM for LEDs stopped working.

Comment: This is likely due to a kernel upgrade. Starting from 4.something the bone-capmanager disappeared and you can't change the pinmux for your cape dynamically. You'll need to write a new device tree overlay to specify the function for your pins.

Comment: Thanks.
 I've been editing /boot/uEnv.txt, like adding the line
`uboot_overlay_addr4=/lib/firmware/BB-UART1-00A0.dtbo` but it I'm still getting 
[    4.423257] bone_capemgr bone_capemgr: slot #4: No compatible property for 'BB-UART1'
[    4.431311] bone_capemgr bone_capemgr: slot #4: Failed verification
[    4.450693] bone_capemgr bone_capemgr: loader: failed to load slot-4 BB-UART1:00A0 (prio 0)